# regex replace chars in one line for emails

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm not good at regex, but I'm trying to find a solution to replace some chars from a list of emails export to my newer db using preg_replace():

```
$patterns1 = '/\[at\]/'; '/\(at\)/'; '/\{at\}/'; '/\ at\ /';
$replacements1 = '@';

$patterns2 = '/\[dot\]/'; '/\(dot\)/'; '/\{dot\}/'; '/\ dot\ /';
$replacements2 = '.';

input:
username [at] subdomain [dot] domain [dot] com
username {at} subdomain {dot} domain {dot} com
username (at) subdomain (dot) domain (dot) com
username at subdomain dot domain dot com
username[at]subdomain[dot]domain[dot]com
username{at}subdomain{dot}domain{dot}com
username(at)subdomain(dot)domain(dot)com

output:
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
username@subdomain.domain.com
```

Comment: spaces are better to be used as \s+. not sure if you want 'let's meet at midnight' to become 'let's meet@midnight' or 'error at line: 10' 'error@line: 10'.

Comment: Without your input / expected output, it is very difficult to give you an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it, this works for me:
`$ echo 'me {at)somewhere dot com' | perl -lane 's/(\s*[({\[ ]at[)}\] ]\s*)/@/g; s/(\s*[({\[ ]dot[)}\] ]\s*)/./g;print'`

your patterns will be `/\s*[({\[ ]at[)}\] ]\s*/` and `/\s*[({\[ ]dot[)}\] ]\s*/`